# Multiple High chart export to single pdf in angular 8 & 9

Tags: highcharts, angular8, jspdf

I have used Highchart in angular 8. I want to export multiple chart single pdf.  I am also using jsPDF.

In angular typescript I can't export to single pdf.

Export and export-offline not working
For downloading Svg image and add to pdf.

Import * as highcharts from 'highchsrts-angulat'

This import not suitable for Highcharts.getSVG().

Can you please anyone provide angular 7 or 8 or 9 version sample export functionality

Comment: Have you already seen the FAQ? It is a really common question: https://www.highcharts.com/docs/getting-started/frequently-asked-questions#can-i-export-multiple-charts-to-the-same-image-or-pdf and here is a demo of this functionality: http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/m9khqe18/. Now all you need to do is to reproduce it in the Angular environment.

Comment: Hi @Sebastian Wedzel. In angular typescript does not recognised the namespace Highcharts. When am trying to access the Highcharts.getSVG() function or any other Highcharts.ExportLocal() function not available.

Comment: May I see your attempt (demo)?